# rust how to make a variable has different types in different conditions

Tags: rust

```rust
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
  let path = std::env::args().nth(1).expect("usage: minidecaf <input path>");
  let input = std::fs::read_to_string(path)?;
  let output_path = std::env::args().nth(2);
  let writer;
  if output_path.is_none() {
      writer = std::io::stdout();
  } else {
      writer = std::fs::File::open(output_path.unwrap()).unwrap();
  }
  minidecaf::run(&input, &mut writer)
}
```

`writer` should be `stdout()` when output_path command line argument is not provided and be `File` when output_path command line argument is provided.
This code does not work, because the type of `writer` cannot be determined in compile time.

I change it to the following. Since both `File` and `Stdout` implements `std::io::Write`, and what I need is a reference to `std::io::Write`. As the signature of function `run` is:

```
pub fn run(input: &str, output: &mut impl std::io::Write) -> std::io::Result<()>
```

```rust
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
  let path = std::env::args().nth(1).expect("usage: minidecaf <input path>");
  let input = std::fs::read_to_string(path)?;
  let output_path = std::env::args().nth(2);
  let mut writer : &mut std::io::Write;
  if output_path.is_none() {
      writer = &mut std::io::stdout();
  } else {
      writer = &mut std::fs::File::open(output_path.unwrap()).unwrap();
  }
  minidecaf::run(&input, &mut writer)
}
```

But it does not work, too. It has lifetime problems.

Then I change it to:

```rust
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
  let path = std::env::args().nth(1).expect("usage: minidecaf <input path>");
  let input = std::fs::read_to_string(path)?;
  let output_path = std::env::args().nth(2);
  minidecaf::run(&input, &mut (if output_path.is_none() {std::io::stdout()} else {std::fs::File::open(output_path.unwrap()).unwrap()}) )
}
```

It has the same problem with the first piece of code.

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:11:83
   |
11 |   minidecaf::run(&input, &mut (if output_path.is_none() {std::io::stdout()} else {std::fs::File::open(output_path.unwrap()).unwrap()}) )
   |                                                          -----------------        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Stdout`, found struct `File`
   |                                                          |
   |                                                          expected because of this
```

So how can I make `writer` be `stdout()` when output_path command line argument is not provided and be `File` when output_path command line argument is provided?

Comment: As a side note, the `&mut` in the type of the `output` parameter for `run()` is unnecessary. Just using `output: impl Write` is more flexible. It will still allow passing in mutable references to values implementing `Write` since the standard library provides forwarding implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, you need `writer` to be some kind of reference to `std::io::Write`, but you also need someone to own the corresponding value. The obvious solution here is to use a `Box`:

```
fn run(input: &str, output: &mut impl std::io::Write) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let path = std::env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .expect("usage: minidecaf <input path>");
    let input = std::fs::read_to_string(path)?;
    let output_path = std::env::args().nth(2);
    let mut writer: Box<dyn std::io::Write>;
    if output_path.is_none() {
        writer = Box::new(std::io::stdout());
    } else {
        writer = Box::new(std::fs::File::open(output_path.unwrap()).unwrap());
    }
    run(&input, &mut writer)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=9221a4dbe5469ad216ac5c1733f74372)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to read more about [how to use trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

Here is a sample code may do what you want:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct A {
    a: usize,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct B {
    b: usize,
}

trait C {
    fn test(&self);
}

impl C for A {
    fn test(&self) {
        println!("A");
    }
}

impl C for B {
    fn test(&self) {
        println!("B");
    }
}


fn main() {
    let t: Box<dyn C> = if true {
        Box::new(A::default())
    } else {
        Box::new(B::default())
    };
    t.test();
}
```

You can try it [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dbb5f1f58aee3533084a45731df116e5)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the overhead of dynamic dispatch, it is possible to use the [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/1.6.1/either/enum.Either.html) type from the [`either`](https://docs.rs/either/1.6.1/either/index.html) crate to wrap the value, which automatically implements all (most?) traits from the standard library if possible:

```rust
use {
    either::Either,
    std::{fs::File, io},
};

let mut writer = match output_path {
    Some(path) => Either::Left(File::open(path)?),
    None => Either::Right(io::stdout()),
};
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62ef949229de2bd11e48cdc79e2eb5a1))

Here, using a `match` expression is conceptually clearer in my opinion.

---

Without using external crates, it is also possible to mimic the behavior of an `Either` enum using variables:

```rust
use std::{env, fs::File, io};

let (mut stdout, mut file);

let writer: &mut dyn io::Write = match output_path {
    Some(path) => {
        file = File::open(path)?;
        &mut file
    }
    None => {
        stdout = io::stdout();
        &mut stdout
    }
};
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=25aa5b013fdb41e02b379b90395e4b86))

Comment: Why the second method works? I think the lifetime of `file` created in match is enclosed by `writer`. I think it only lasts until the right brace ends.

Comment: @Tokubara Since the value is assigned to `file`, its lifetime is bound to `file` as well.